# After moving TinyMCEditor around

Tags: php, tinymce, modx, magic-quotes

I moved ModX to a new location. Inside ModX there is a TinyMCEditor.

After the move, if I paste html into it, TinyMCEditor is replacing all my content with strange words and backslashes.

Old content which worked in old TinyMCEditor :

```
<img src="assets/images/Screen shot 2011-08-16 at 2.36.55 PM.png" alt="" width="145" height="60" />
```

After paste:

```
<img src="\&quot;assets/images/Screen" alt="\&quot;\&quot;" width="\&quot;145\&quot;" height="\&quot;60\&quot;" />
```

So not only does it remove the actual image, but it also throw those `&quot;` jobbies in there too.

**Update**

I have deduced this problem having something to do with PHP's Magic Quotes as reflected here :

[Magic Quotes Link](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE_FAQ#Why_does_my_HTML_output_include_lots_of_.5C.22_like_.3Ca_href.3D.5C.22mylink.htm.5C.22.3Elink.3C.2Fa.3E.3F)

But this is a shared server, and I don't see a PHP.ini file available anywhere. Is it still possible to edit this option?

Answer (score 0):

You can try altering the .htaccess file for the server and add

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

Otherwise you will need to strip the slashes on all input before saving it.

ref

*http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php*